# How to add an onClickListener that would open a new activity to a Fragment activity

Tags: java, android, xml, button, onclick

I'm fairly new to android studio so I will try to explain as best as I can.
I've made a menu using fragments, so my `activity_home` is a fragmented activity. Inside the fragmented activity I've created a button that, upon clicking, should open a new activity.

The problem is that I don't know how to implement the `onClickListener` inside the fragmented activity.

Every tutorial I went trough does it from the beginning.
This is my main activity:

```
package com.example.relja.diplomskirad;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new home(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new profil(), "Profil");
        adapter.addFragment(new mapa(), "Mapa");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


}
```

This is my main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is home.java where i want to put the onclick listener:

```
package com.example.relja.diplomskirad;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class home extends Fragment {

    public home() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

    }

}
```

And this is home xml where the button is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".home">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/glavnaStranica1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoSlika"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/glavnaStranica2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:background="@drawable/ivica"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dugme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dugme"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dugmeLogin"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/dugmeLogin"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="loginLogin"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you simply just perform onClickListener in your fragment then write onclicklistener in your fragment ii self and if you want on click of your fragment in your parent fragmentActivity then you need to use the callback.

Comment: One thing I do not understand that this question comes up every week two-three times, how? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.. this will help

```
 public class home extends Fragment {
       private Button btn_dumge_login;

        public home() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

        }
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

         btn_dumge_login = view.findViewById(R.id.dumgeLogin)
           btn_dumge_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TestActivity.class) ;
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: welcome bro.. please accept my answer and give upvote so that something facing this problem can understand which one right and working

Comment: I cant upvote because i am new here and it wont let me. But i accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file, container, false);
view.findViewById(R.id.button_id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), YourNewActivity.class));
});
return view;
```

you can use this code in your fragment 'home' in onCreateView() method

Answer (score 0):

You should select first the view you want to be navigated from, for example, the Button with id dugmeLogin

then your code should be something like that

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

    Button loginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.dugmeLogin);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // You code goes here
    });
    return view;


}
```

this is in your home.java